# How can I get request id after sending app request in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm sending app request from iphone app using the following method of Facebook SDK

```
-(void)dialog:(NSString *)action andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params andDelegate:(id <FBDialogDelegate>)delegate;
```

and implemented `-(void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog` to get return.
I'm wondering there's a way of getting request id of succeeded app request? "dialog" sent to delegate doesn't contain any information about request id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `dialogDidCompleteWithURL:` method instead. The URL passed to you in that method contains the request ID(s). It is up to you to parse them from the URL.

Comment: This was helpful. But the method is 'dialogCompleteWithUrl:'